# c++ Pointer to another class bug "no operator matches these operands."

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators

edit*
 I'm dumb... Thanks for helping me this question is solved.
*
In my **car** class the code below keeps giving me an error on the << operators

```
cout << "Driver: " << driver->print(); 
cout << "Owner: " << owner->print();
```

The error says "no operator matches these operands." This is my homework assignment so I do need to somehow from the driver call the print function. In the main function I'm not actually setting the driver or owner yet but that shouldn't matter I wouldn't think. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
Person(string _name,int _age)
{
    _name = name;
    _age = age;
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
}
string getName()
{
    return name;
}
int getAge()
{
    return age;
}
int incrementAge()
{
    age +=1;
    return age;
}
void print()
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << age << endl;

}


private:
string name;
int age;

};

class Car
{
public:
Car (string m)
{
    model = m;
}
void setDriver(Person *d)
{
    *driver = *d;
}
void setOwner(Person *o)
{
    *owner = *o;
}
void print()
{
    cout << "Model: " << model << endl;
    cout << "Driver: " << driver->print();
    cout << "Owner: " << owner->print();
}




private:

string model;
Person *owner;
Person *driver;


};

int main()
{
vector<Person*>people;
vector<Car*>cars;
string name = "";
int age = 0;
string model = 0;
int sentValue = 0;
while (sentValue != -1)
{
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter age: ";
    cin >> age;


    people.push_back(new Person(name, age));
    cout << "Enter car model: ";
    cin >> model;
            cars.push_back(new Car(model));
    cout << "Press -1 to stop, or 1 to enter info for others: ";
    cin >> sentValue;
}






//display car model, 
//owner’s name and age,
//and driver’s name and age.

system("pause");
return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You call compiler errors "bugs" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print() function already sends the output to `cout`, so there is no need to try to send it there again. Instead of

```
cout << "Driver: " << driver->print();
```

you probably want

```
cout << "Driver:" << endl;
driver->print();
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I probably should get some sleep now lol after that.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ way of doing this would be to implement `std::ostream&<<` operators for `Person` and `Car`. For example,

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Person& p) {
  return o << "Name: " << p.getName() << " Age: " << p.getAge();
}
```

then use like this:

```
Person p("Bob", 23);
std::cout << p << "\n";
```

As an aside, I don't think you really need all those pointers in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The member functions `print` return `void`. You can't insert a `void` into a stream. If you change the print functions to take a stream reference and add overloaded operators that call print, you can just insert the objects themselves into the stream; that would be more idiomatic.

```
template <class Elem, class Traits>
void Car::print(std::ostream<Elem, Traits>& out) {
    out << "Model: " << model << '\n';
    out << "Driver: " << *driver;
    out << "Owner: " << *owner;
}

template <class Elem, class Traits>
std::ostream<Elem, Traits>& out, const Car& car) {
    return out << car;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Driver: " << driver->print();
```

your `<<` waiting for an appropriate object to process. That is your problem. Rather than implementing `print()`, overload the operator by implementing `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);` and let the C++ do the rest. Then you can print like that:

```
 cout << "Driver: " << driver;
```

Comment: `toString()?` This isn't java. The canonical way would be to implement `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);`.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for reminding me, I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But note that C++11 has added `std::to_string` that actually can be useful, at least for some types.

Comment: @JerryCoffin sure, but I prefer the idea of having an output stream operator. If it uses strings in the implementation is another matter.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oh, no argument from me on that (in fact, one of the up-votes on your answer is from me).

Answer (score 0):

```
const std::string& Person::print() const
{
    return "Name " + name + "\n" + "Age " + age + "\n";    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can return reference `std::string&` in this case?